# ways for Android record screen background

Tags: android

I want to implement an application to record the Android screen. Either root or non-root is ok, I know there are some apps do the same things, such as recordable(non-root)...

My question is that, Is there a way or method to implement it myself? So do not recommend any app for me!

More details, does anybody know Recordable (an recording app) works, why it need to connect computer to complete installation. Any tips is welcome~

Answer (score 0):

For Android Kitkat and above, you can just use the simple ADB command called "screenrecord" (links [**here**](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/kitkat.html#44-screen-recording) and [**here**](http://www.androidcentral.com/android-screen-record-kitkat)) .

Example:

```
adb shell screenrecord /sdcard/demo.mp4
```

If you connect the device to a PC, all you need to do is to call this command via the PC.

If you use only the device, you'll need to use root, so you simply have to call it once you get root permission. A nice root library can be found [**here**](https://github.com/Chainfire/libsuperuser).

As for previous Android versions, they usually don't work well. My guess is that they constantly take screenshots and then stitch them together.

Answer (score 0):

If you want write your own code for 'screenrecord' command, check this out:
https://github.com/adouggy/MyRecorder